# Add timeline to Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I was wondering if there's a way to add a script to Bootstrap's carousel, so it will show the images within a timeline. Say, I want an image to be shown between march 05 and when it's march 11, the image should disappear. I've been able to do this with other slideshows, like pikachoose, but I can't find a way to do this with Bootstrap's carousel.

The script I've used before is this one

```
        $(document).ready(
            function (){

                //Users time
                var timeLocal = new Date();

                var AllImages = $(".item");

                var liEndDate;
                var imgEndDate;

                var liStartDate;
                var imgStartDate;

                var thisImg;

                for (var i = 0; i < AllImages.length; i++) {

                    thisImg = AllImages[i];

                    liEndDate = thisImg.getAttribute("endDate");
                    imgEndDate = new Date(liEndDate);

                    liStartDate = thisImg.getAttribute("startDate");
                    imgStartDate = new Date(liStartDate);

                    if (imgStartDate > timeLocal || imgEndDate < timeLocal || liEndDate == null || liStartDate == null ) { // si timeLocal es menor a TheNext, entonces haga esto.\

                        //document.write(AllImages[i].outerHTML);
                        $(thisImg).remove();

                    } else {

                        $(thisImg).show();
                    }

                });

    </script>
```

But I haven't been able to adapt it to the carousel
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to change the code and sort of make it work. However, this hides the entire slideshow for the moment the image is supposed to be hidden.

```
<script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(
                function () {

                    //Users time
                    var timeLocal = new Date();

                    var AllImages = $(".item img");

                    var liEndDate;
                    var imgEndDate;

                    var liStartDate;
                    var imgStartDate;

                    var thisImg;

                    for (var i = 0; i < AllImages.length; i++) {

                        thisImg = AllImages[i];

                        liEndDate = thisImg.getAttribute("endDate");
                        imgEndDate = new Date(liEndDate);

                        liStartDate = thisImg.getAttribute("startDate");
                        imgStartDate = new Date(liStartDate);

                        if (imgStartDate > timeLocal || imgEndDate < timeLocal || liEndDate === null || liStartDate === null) { // si timeLocal es menor a TheNext, entonces haga esto.\

                            //document.write(AllImages[i].outerHTML);
                            $(thisImg).remove();

                        } else {

                            $(thisImg).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

    </script>
```